# Porque as views ficaram lentas após migrar os dados via script no Firebird 2.5?

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-2.5

Estou trabalhando em uma base de dados padronizada. Recentemente refatorei a estrutura dela (A) renomeando todas as PK e FK existentes, porque tinham os nomes que são gerados automaticamente.
Ao migrar os dados de uma outra base (B) para esta refatorada (A), agora estou tendo uma lentidão muito grande na leitura de algumas views, mesmo elas possuindo a mesma estrutura.

Ao analisar a performance, reparei que na base nova (A) estão sendo lidos muito mais registros que na anterior, para exatamente a mesma consulta. Porém não consegui entender porque isso acontece. 
Abaixo o print da análise de performance.

[image: performance analysis]

Comment: https://www.upscene.com/documentation/dbw3/index.html?fb_db_databasestatistics.htm   Estatiscas atualizadas ?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Motta, eu já tinha tentado mas isso não tinha resolvido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, foi só recompilar a view. Bom, não entendi porque, mas felizmente o problema está resolvido!